# Why was my question closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

My question was asked January 14th 2012
[What happened to the Grid at the end of Tron Legacy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9091/what-happened-to-the-grid-at-the-end-of-tron-legacy#comment54045_9091)

This morning it was closed as an exact duplicate because someone on November 17th 2012 asked the same question? [What happens to the grid if the system is shut down](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26927/what-happens-to-the-grid-if-the-system-is-shut-down)

How is my question a duplicate if I asked it 10 months *before* the other question existed?

Comment: frown upon @PearsonArtPhoto

Comment: The word "duplicate" implies nothing to do with time, it just means they're the same question.  I'd guess yours was closed because it had only one answer (vs 3) at the time the duplication was noticed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just was handling a flag, I should have cbecked the date... Anyways, I've reversed the closure.

Comment: Thank you for speedy resolution. This is how moderation ought to work.